# Looking for information on how to fix problems with this div table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I almost managed to get everything set, but have run into a few weird issues that I can't seem to figure out no matter how much I try. The problems I'm running into are:

1. Spacing is too big on the right side.
2. Tables always stack under the other (without any spacing). I've been trying to have it so it can fit as many columns of "boxes" as possible (with spaces between each of course) before making a new row depending on how wide someone's resolution is.
3. Bizarrely, for some reason the image for the right side's border seems to be showing up wrong/is the left side. I've tried multiple things and still can't seem to fix it. The image file is correct so I'm not sure why it keeps showing the wrong one.  - **Seemed to have fixed this one!**
4. At the moment, I need to essentially repaste the entire TR code rather than just doing `<div>*infohere*</div>` or the first box just gets stretched further (as shown in the first example of the jsfiddle). Is there any way I could have it so I'd just have to do the `div`s? Or is that impossible for what I want to do?

CSS:

```
table#t_gallery, table#t_content{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}

table#t_gallery {
    margin-top:12px;
}

table#t_gallery td {
    padding:0px;
}

#t_gallery_top, #t_gallery_bottom {
    background: url("/top.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    height:6px;
    width:265px;
}

#t_gallery_bottom {
    background-image:url("/bottom.png");
}

#t_gallery_left, #t_gallery_right {
    background: rgba(11, 14, 15, .5) url("/left.png") 0 0 repeat-y;
    width:6px;
}

#t_gallery_right {
    background-image:url("/right.png");
}

#t_gallery_middle {
    background-color: rgba(11, 14, 15, .65);
    width:252px;
}

#t_gallery_middle div{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 10px 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/0waobznt/
**What I'm trying to aim for:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIJRk.png

Comment: This layouts must not be doing with tables. You'll achieve problems in all areas. Change to simply divs with inline block or float or flexbox and it works, perfectly and without surprises

Comment: I'll try looking into that then--I don't have much experience with divs alone unfortunately. CSS & Divs are things I'm still not very confident with just yet.

Comment: Have a look at `display:flex`, should do what you are after, using divs too, which will make your code more semantically correct - never use tables for layout, they should be used for tabular data only

Comment: Layouts with tables is a thing from last century, so if you need to make layouts now you must to learn some CSS. I don't know how can I help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have modified your code to get the result wanted in the image. 
Try to use the following code

```css
table#t_gallery, table#t_content{
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:0px;
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:0px;
  
}
table#t_global{
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:20px;
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:0px;
  
}
table#t_gallery {
 margin-top:12px;
}

table#t_gallery td {
 padding:0px;
}
table#t_gallery tr {

  margin:20px !important;
}
#t_gallery_top, #t_gallery_bottom {
 background: url("http://seac.crystal-dreams.us/top.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
 height:6px;
 width:265px;
}

#t_gallery_bottom {
 background-image:url("http://seac.crystal-dreams.us/bottom.png");
}

#t_gallery_left, #t_gallery_right {
 background: rgba(11, 14, 15, .5) url("http://seac.crystal-dreams.us/left.png") 0 0 repeat-y;
 width:6px;
}

#t_gallery_right {
 background-image:url("http://seac.crystal-dreams.us/right.png");
}

#t_gallery_middle {
 background-color: rgba(11, 14, 15, .65);
 width:252px;
  text-align:center;
 border-spacing:100px;
}

#t_gallery_middle div{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px 10px 5px;

}
```

```html
<table id="t_global">
<tr><td><table id="t_gallery">
  <tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_top" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr><tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_left"> </td>
 <td id="t_gallery_middle"> 

 <!-- Do not edit above //-->
 
<div >
    <a href="http://angelears.crystal-dreams.us/blanksc.png" rel="gallery-mcplush" title="Blankness"><img src="http://seac.crystal-dreams.us/blanksc.png" width="200" height="200" border="0"></a> <br>
    Unknown item<br>
        Gotten from: Unknown<br>
        Still Available: Unknown</div>       
    
   
 <!-- Do not edit below //-->
 </td>
 <td id="t_gallery_right"> </td>
  </tr><tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_bottom" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  

</table></td><td><table id="t_gallery">
  <tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_top" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr><tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_left"> </td>
 <td id="t_gallery_middle"> 

 <!-- Do not edit above //-->
 
<div >
    <a href="http://angelears.crystal-dreams.us/blanksc.png" rel="gallery-mcplush" title="Blankness"><img src="http://seac.crystal-dreams.us/blanksc.png" width="200" height="200" border="0"></a> <br>
    Unknown item<br>
        Gotten from: Unknown<br>
        Still Available: Unknown</div>       
    
   
 <!-- Do not edit below //-->
 </td>
 <td id="t_gallery_right"> </td>
  </tr><tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_bottom" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  

</table></td><td><table id="t_gallery">
  <tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_top" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr><tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_left"> </td>
 <td id="t_gallery_middle"> 

 <!-- Do not edit above //-->
 
<div >
    <a href="http://angelears.crystal-dreams.us/blanksc.png" rel="gallery-mcplush" title="Blankness"><img src="http://seac.crystal-dreams.us/blanksc.png" width="200" height="200" border="0"></a> <br>
    Unknown item<br>
        Gotten from: Unknown<br>
        Still Available: Unknown</div>       
    
   
 <!-- Do not edit below //-->
 </td>
 <td id="t_gallery_right"> </td>
  </tr><tr>
 <td id="t_gallery_bottom" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  

</table></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!